# How to delete specific digit from integer?

Tags: java, arrays, integer

In the `n` integer  where `n = 1237534` (for example) I have to delete digit `3` so I can get the biggest value possible. `n` can be negative number also.

I can get `127534` or `123754`.

The bigger is of course `127534`, but how can I return it?

I've tried something like this:

```java
int n = 1237534;

String newNum = String.valueOf(n);

int[] newGuess = new int[newNum.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < newNum.length(); i++) {
    newGuess[i] = newNum.charAt(i) - '0';
}

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < newGuess.length; i++) {
    if (!(newGuess[i] % 3 == 0)) {
        sb.append(newGuess[i]);
    }
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

I get `12754` which is not correct answer. Anyone maybe have an idea how to solve it?

Comment: `charAt()` would return the first occurrence of 3. The you can use substring to remove it. `String result = str.substring(0, index) + str.substring(index+1);` No need for loops. I am not even sure what they are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not require arrays nor loops:

```
int n = 1237534;

String newNum = String.valueOf(n);
char c = '3';
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder( newNum );
StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder( newNum );

int newGuess1 = Integer.parseInt(sb1.deleteCharAt(newNum.indexOf(c)).toString());
int newGuess2 = Integer.parseInt(sb2.deleteCharAt(newNum.indexOf(c, newNum.indexOf(c)+1)).toString());

System.out.println( newGuess1 > newGuess2 ? newGuess1: newGuess2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```java
int n = 123454321;
int bad_digit = 3;

StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(n + "");
s.reverse();
System.out.println("Reversed String: " + s);
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    // Check if the character at index 'i' and the
    // digit are equal, by converting both to strings
    if (("" + s.charAt(i)).equals("" + bad_digit)) {
        s.replace(i, i + 1, "");
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println("Reversed String after removing the digit (if found): " + s);
s.reverse();

System.out.println("Greatest number without the bad digit: " + s);
```

Basically, we need to remove the last occurrence of the digit to be removed (the `bad_digit`). So we convert the number to a string and reverse it. Now we need to remove the **first** occurrence of the digit. So we iterate over the characters, and when we find that digit, we remove it from the string, and exit the loop. Now we reverse the string again, and the output is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach that also checks to ensure that the number actually contains the digit.  Otherwise, an exception could be thrown if the index returns -1.

The method simply deletes the first or last occurrence of the digit depending on whether the number is negative or not.

```
int n = 1234321;
int bad_digit = 3;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(n));
String bad = Integer.toString(bad_digit);
int idxOfFirst = sb.indexOf(bad);

// first, make certain the number contains the digit.
if (idxOfFirst >= 0) {
    if (sb.charAt(0) == '-') {
        // if negative, delete last character to give the larger value
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.lastIndexOf(bad));
    } else {
        // else delete the first character to give the larger value
        sb.deleteCharAt(idxOfFirst);
    }
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

This prints the string rather than convert to an integer since printing an integer results in conversion to a string anyway.  If the digit does not appear in the original number, then the original is printed.  You can alter that handling to meet your requirements.